# get store data and dispatch outer component react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga, redux-persist

I need to access redux store data and dispatch function outer the react component (in utils function)

I use React Native, Redux, Redux Saga, Redux Persist. my config store file is like below:

```
//create the saga middleware
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const encryptor = createEncryptor({
secretKey: 'encryptor_key',
  onError(error) {
  console.log('Encryptor error', error);
  // Handle the error.
 },
});

const persistConfig = {
   key: 'root',
   storage,
   transforms: [encryptor],
   whitelist: ['user', 'etc'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default () => {
   const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
const persistor = persistStore(store);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
 return { store, persistor };
};
```

after user login, I save user info and oath2 token in user reducer in redux and persist that with Redux Persist. App.js is like below code:

```
 import configureStore from './services/configureStore';
 const { store, persistor } = configureStore();

 render() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
       <PersistGate loading={<Loading style={{ flex: 1 }} />} persistor={persistor}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

now, in api.js I need to access user token. I need to check oauth2 token expire time before each axios request. before axios send request I call setHeader function. my code in api.js is like below:

```
import configureStore from './configureStore'; //import config store

function setHeader(){
    const { store, persistor } = configureStore();
    console.log('store is:', store.getState())
}
```

when I call setHeader function console.log show store is empty, instead of show redux store data.
anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the store in App.js, so just export the store from there:

```
const { store, persistor } = configureStore();

export {store}
```

Afterwards you have access to the store anywhere by simply importing it:

```
import {store} from ./???/App.js
```

Comment: I thinks it's a correct answer but I can't test now, I test this code 3 days later.

Comment: That's okay, best of luck!

Comment: It was a correct answer. but I use this solution with little change in my code. I call configureStore() in configureStore.js file and export {store, persistor} in configstore.js so in app.js and utils.js I import {store, persistor}

Comment: Alright! If it worked you can accept my answer as being correct for future reference. I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have access to Store in Provider and App.js file. And if we consider `setHeader` as an action of redux, you can simply use following code to get your states:

```
function setHeader() { //Thunk Action
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log(getState())
    }
}
```

Comment: setHeader is not an action of redux. setHeader is an utils function outer the components and I need access to store data in this function